# How to generate Bayer matrix of arbitrary size?

Tags: algorithm

In [ordered dithering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_dithering) Bayer matrix is used.

How is that matrix generated? What algorithm can be used to generate matrix of arbitrary size?

Comment: Have you actually read the wikipedia page you linked? Let me try to summarize it in an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(As @Bálint seems not to have gotten around to it… :)

To quote the article as it (likely) was when you initially asked:

> Arbitrary size threshold maps can be devised with a simple rule: First fill
>   each slot with a successive integer starting from 1. Then reorder them such
>   that the average distance between two successive numbers in the map is as
>   large as possible, ensuring that the table "wraps" around at edges.

A more detailed explanation has since been added to the article:

> For threshold maps whose dimensions are a power of two, the map can be generated recursively via:
>   [image]
>
> The recursive expression can be calculated explicitly using only bit arithmetic:
>   
>   `M(i, j) = bit_reverse(bit_interleave(bitwise_xor(x, y), x)) / n ^ 2`

That last bit can be implemented with little trouble in e.g. Python:

```python
def bit_reverse(x, n):
    return int(bin(x)[2:].zfill(n)[::-1], 2)

def bit_interleave(x, y, n):
    x = bin(x)[2:].zfill(n)
    y = bin(y)[2:].zfill(n)
    return int(''.join(''.join(i) for i in zip(x, y)), 2)

def bayer_entry(x, y, n):
    return bit_reverse(bit_interleave(x ^ y, y, n), 2*n)

def bayer_matrix(n):
    r = range(2**n)
    return [[bayer_entry(x, y, n) for x in r] for y in r]

print(bayer_matrix(2))
```

This doesn't produce *quite* the same matrix as listed in the Wikipedia article, but as the author of the [original source](http://bisqwit.iki.fi/story/howto/dither/jy/) writes, "it is good enough in practice".

Comment: For `bayer_matrix(1)`, and the sake of brevity, your code generates `[[0, 1], [3, 2]]` but for correct results (when doing ordered dithering) I expect it to be `[[0, 2], [3, 1]]`?